# I can´t execute my app on my phone sdk old, I must change my gradle?

Tags: android, api, apk

I´m using Android Studio version 3, I´m trying to execute my simple app, but this comes out:

```
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.jhon.pasardatosentreactivities
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]


Installation failed since app's minSdkVersion is newer than device's API level (API 1).
Please update your apps minSdkVersion.
Error while Installing APK
```

I have to de some sort of update on my phone? Or I have to change may gradle?

Note: The code is very short, I don´t think is necessary.

gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jhon.pasardatosentreactivities"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Please make the answer with detail, I'm new on this.

Comment: What device are you trying to install this on?

Comment: Huawei p9 lite ....

Comment: Your device was released with Android 6.0, API 23, so your `minSdkVersion` should be 23 or lower based upon what devices/libraries you are trying to support.

Comment: `minSdkVersion 27` means that your app won't install on devices with SDK lower than 27

Comment: minSdkVersion 23 works, the rest, 28. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jhon.pasardatosentreactivities"
        minSdkVersion 1  //set this equal to your target device's android api level
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

But support libraries have smallest API level limitation which greater than 1 , so I suggest you update device OS or buy newer phone.

Comment: Targeting 28 has a minimum SDK limit of 14. It can't be set to 1. Since the device OP is using is newer than the first version of Android, this answer won't work for 2 reasons.